# Setting up GeoServer JNDI

Tags: http, tomcat, jndi, geoserver

I am attempting to set up GeoServer JNDI. Nevertheless, I received HTTP 503. Before setting up JNDI, I uploaded a shapefile in GeoServer and could access it from QGIS in a local machine. However, I have a problem to access to geoserver after setting up JNDI.

What I have done is

1. Downloaded jdbcconfig (`PostgreSQL JDBC 4.2 Driver, 42.2.5`) from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html.
2. Extracted this file and placed the JARs in `/usr/local/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib` (the two JARs are `gs-jdbcconfig-2.14-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar`
3. Added the following to `/Library/Tomcat/conf/context.xml`

   ```
       <Resource name="jdbc/postgres"
       auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource"
       driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
       url="jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>"
       username="" password=""
       maxActive="20"
       initialSize="0"
       minIdle="0"
       maxIdle="8"
       maxWait="10000"
       timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
       minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
       testWhileIdle="true"
       validationQuery="SELECT 1"
       maxAge="600000" <!-- only on Tomcat >= 7 -->
       rollbackOnReturn="true" <!-- only on Tomcat >= 7 -->
       />
   ```
4. Restarting geoserver, `jdbcconfig` was created in `data_dir`
5. Configured `/usr/local/geoserver/data_dir/jdbcconfig` -- set `enabled = true`, `initdb = true` and `import = true`.
6. Started Geoserver again. I received `HTTP ERROR: 503`.

It looks like my edits make Tomcat crash. As I did

```
$tail -f logs/catalina.out
```

I received

```
17-Dec-2018 10:43:49.232 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Context/Context/Valve'.
17-Dec-2018 10:43:49.232 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Context/Context/Manager'.
17-Dec-2018 10:43:49.232 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Context/Context'.
17-Dec-2018 10:43:49.238 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
17-Dec-2018 10:43:49.238 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more components marked the context as not correctly configured
17-Dec-2018 10:43:49.239 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/host-manager] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Dec-2018 10:43:49.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Library/Tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [12] ms
17-Dec-2018 10:43:49.241 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Dec-2018 10:43:49.247 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Dec-2018 10:43:49.248 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 262 ms`
```

How could I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to look further back to find the "previous errors", I don't think the driver will connect with out a username or password

Comment: I have a username and password in configuration. I just deleted them for publishing a public question.